# dynamic_reconfigure (python) changes in fuerte

Tags: dynamic-reconfigure

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I recently migrated to fuerte and noticed that the sick_ldmrs driver is broken due to some changes in dynamic_reconfigure python's API in fuerte.

```
"apply_changes" in config
```

had to be changed to

```
"apply_changes" in config.__dict__
```

,

```
self.ros_params = config.copy()
```

had to be changed to

```
self.ros_params = copy.deepcopy(config.__dict__)
```

,

```
for param_name, value in config.iteritems()
```

had to be changed to

```
for param_name, value in config.items()
```

Accessing the **dict** from outside of the class seems an ugly trick to me. Because it's a super-private variable... Is there any other way this could be achieved?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/36526/dynamic_reconfigure-(python)-changes-in-fuerte/) by [brice rebsamen](https://answers.ros.org/users/597/brice-rebsamen/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1001 on 2012-06-14

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

That looks like a bug to me.

To get it fixed, please [open a defect ticket](https://kforge.ros.org/dynamicreconfig/trac/newticket?component=dynamic_reconfigure&type=defect&&dynamic_reconfigure), which can link back to this question.

---

Originally posted by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) with karma: 25443 on 2012-06-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [brice rebsamen](https://answers.ros.org/users/597/brice-rebsamen/) on 2012-06-25**:
Thanks for the tip: https://kforge.ros.org/dynamicreconfig/trac/ticket/4

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Basically this was a defect in some of the code I wrote last year to support parameter groups and has been fixed in the latest version of dynamic_reconfigure which you can get [here](http://kforge.ros.org/dynamicreconfig/hg) and will be in the next release of dynamic_reconfigure.

---

Originally posted by [klapow](https://answers.ros.org/users/2577/klapow/) with karma: 56 on 2012-06-25

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [brice rebsamen](https://answers.ros.org/users/597/brice-rebsamen/) on 2012-08-07**:
Got the fix, sickldmrs is working out of the box now.